# How to add a space, break or div at specific height dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, pdf

So basically I want to print out a page as a pdf from a react app, that include multiple components. number of components change from 4 up to 12 and the height of the components also change based on content from the store.

I need every 900px(size of my a4 page) to add a space so that none of the components get split between pages. or to split the hole page in to even 900px parts based on how many components are rendered.

Comment: Are you talking about printing into a PDF on the client side using the print dialog, or about rendering an HTML document into a PDF using any server-side techniques or scripts?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am trying to print on the client side using Jspdf and html2canvas npm, this is the best option so far that I found for my specific scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a question can be answered with code snippet. I will explain how i would tackle with this problem.

Steps right after the the print event (on button click or automated...)

1. I would get each components current height (as you mentioned 4 up to 12 components)

```js
   const element = document.getElementById('element');
   element.offsetHeight // height
```

2. I would create placeholder component (div), which would be used to fill the gap vertically between components to be printed.

```
   const Placeholder = ({height}) => (
      <div style={{height: `${height}px` }}>  </div>
   )
```

3. I would start looping all the components until they can fit into 900px. When the chunk reaches the 900px i would fill the gap with placeholder component. That would force rest of the components to move to next page.
   E.g. Let's say:

```sh
Component 1 is 300px
Component 2 is 300px
Component 3 is 700px
Component 4 is 300px
```

```js
loop {
  // first page
  <Component1 />
  <Component2 />
  <Placeholder height={300} />
  // second page
  <Component3 />
  <Placeholder height={200} />
  <Component4 />
  <Placeholder height={600} />
}
```